# Deleting at specific position in a defined LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception

I have this school activity where we are asked to create our own class that implements a LinkedList. I have this problem regarding deleting nodes at a specific position. Can someone help me with this one? Please see attached screenshot:

[image: Original problem statement]

I'll appreciate also if maybe you can help me with this additional functions:

[image: Description of bonus functions]

This is what I came up so far:

```
public void deleteAtPosition(int position){
    if(isEmpty()){
        error_message("The list is empty. Try to add a value.");
    }
    else if(position == 0){
        deleteAtFirst();
    }
    else if (position < 0 || position >= currentSize()){
        error_message("Position is NOT valid.");
    }
    else{
        LNode visit, link, pointer;
        visit=link=pointer=head;
        int ctr = 0;
        while(ctr != position){
            visit = visit.next;
            ctr++;
        }
        while(link.next != visit){
            link = link.next;
        }
        ctr = 1;
        while(ctr != position){
            pointer = pointer.next;
            ctr--;
        }
        link.next = pointer;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you are close. The last loop probably never ends. If `position` is 2 or 7 and you set `ctr` to 1 and decrement it each time,  they will never be equal (or only after `pointer` has run over the end of the list and caused a `NullPointerException`).

Comment: Which undesired behaviour do you observe? Is your method deleting the wrong nodes, too many nodes, nothing at all or giving an error message? When asking about code that does not work, please *always* be *very specific and precise* about which problem you are seeing. In the question (you can edit it).

Comment: *"maybe you can help me with this additional functions"*: that's too broad. Ask about one specific issue you encounter. A question should be *one* question only.

Comment: It is surprising that an algorithm to delete a node from a linked list would need **three** loops. What is wrong with the usual way to just do it with one loop? I don't think this is good learning material, also indicated by how the author uses the word "code".